# Can a .file (.htpasswd) be accessed via browser?

Tags: security, .htpasswd

I was reading this [How secure is .htaccess password protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441578/how-secure-is-htaccess-password-protection) and reviewing the fact that one of my sites has the .htpasswd file in a web facing directory.

But, if the permissions on a .htpasswd file are correct (644), can it be accessed at all via a browser or any other means?

I guess the real question is whether or not I should follow the advice and move the .htpasswd to `/home/user` rather than `/home/user/public_html`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww it is so different from the quoted question, and that was acceptable (with over 80 votes for Q and A) wasn't it?

Comment: In fact, the most popular answer on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134306/where-do-i-post-questions-about-dev-ops  finishes with "DevOps questions should be allowed on Stack Overflow."

Comment: How is a security question not in scope for stack overflow?